# load hbm.xml files from multiple jars using spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

My spring-boot project depends on 2 jars (say a.jar, b.jar) each of them having a few hbm.xml files.
Running app using spring-boot:run, i noticed that only hbm xmls from a.jar are loaded but none of b.jar.
Is there something that needs to be configured on spring.jpa properties?
Is there any property to set jarFileUrls on persistence unit?

Thanks!
V.

Answer (score 1):

for adding some jar file you can add to resource like this

```
@Value("classpath*:lib/framework-*.jar") 
private Resource[] JAR_RESOURCES;

@Value("classpath*:hibernate/**/*.hbm.xml") 
private Resource[] HIBERNATE_HBM_RESOURCES; 

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setMappingJarLocations(JAR_RESOURCES);
    sessionFactoryBean.setMappingLocations(HIBERNATE_HBM_RESOURCES);
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```